# Pycharm show a python file like a text file, how to fix?

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

I have `Pycharm.2016.2.3`, I use `Django 1.9.4` and `Python 3.5.1`.

**The problem**: Pycharm works good until today, but today he show only `forms.py` like a file text.

**Note:** `forms.py` is a `Python File` with extention `*.py` but rest of `Python File` it's shows good. The code works good, the imports works, but when I try to import something from `forms.py` pycharm don't autocmplete.

**PS** I have this problem in all pycharm project, and the default files from `Django` with `forms` is shows like text file.

[image]

Comment: Ahhh, I had this exact same problem in the past. I don't remember the cause, but somewhere in a Pycharm configuration you will probably have a line mapping `forms.py` to plain text type. What I did was to `grep` all my Pycharm configuration files (I don't remember exactly where these are stored since I don't use Pycharm anymore) for the filename (in your case `forms.py`. The line will be in some xml file, and should be obvious. Get rid of that line (or lines) and you should be good. If you want, you can show the line here so that I can confirm before deleting.